# Как сделать, чтобы телеграм бот, написанный на Python, отвечал на разные сообщения главным меню?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Я написала телеграм бота на Python, c Inline кнопками, после команды /start у меня выпадает главное меню, в котором содержатся кнопки с названиями городов, мне надо чтобы это меню появлялось при отправки боту любого сообщения, а ни только команды /start

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Так как ты ловишь хэндлером команды, а надо текст

Попробуй `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])`

Comment: У меня и так там текст

Comment: @Alexander ну так скидывай код с вопросом, как мне знать че ты там написал